# How get size of lockscreen's widget area?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

Is there any method to know auto resizing widget size in pixels before placing this widget on lockscreen? 
For example when we place a widget on lockscreen then configuration activity started and how this activity can get size of widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, an app can't determine a widget's size until the user places the widget on the (lock or home) screen. Even then, the OS returns a size *range* [**why?**] and of course the user can resize the widget.

E.g. add this debug code to an AppWidgetProvider's `onUpdate()` method:

```
    Bundle newOptions = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(appWidgetIds[0]);
    int minWidth = newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH);
    int minHeight = newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT);
    int maxWidth = newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH);
    int maxHeight = newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT);
    Log.i("getAppWidgetOptions", String.format(
            "getAppWidgetOptions %d x %d .. %d x %d",
            minWidth, minHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight));
```

Running on a Nexus 4 emulator, a newly placed home screen widget reports: `240 x 58 .. 302 x 84` in dp units. This is with `<appwidget-provider>` XML that sets:

```
android:minWidth="180dp"
android:minHeight="40dp"
android:minResizeWidth="180dp"
android:minResizeHeight="40dp"
```

An AppWidgetProvider can detect when its widgets resize by overriding `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions)`. With similar code as above [but omit the `getAppWidgetOptions()` call], it logs ranges like `240 x 58 .. 302 x 84` and (after manually stretching the widget wider) `328 x 58 .. 408 x 84`.

Even on the lock screen, a widget can take screen space from the lock keypad if the user drags down over it, although I'm not sure if that changes these min/max size values.

Comment: Yep. I'm afraid you're right. There is no way to get size of lockscreen's widget area.